# Camera Preview with overlay for tracking with a close button

Tags: camera

I have a picamera script that starts the camera_preview and adds a cross hair overlay so that the spotlight operator can target the right person.

As the displays are touch screen I would like to add a button to the top right that will stop the preview and shut down the Pi.

I also need to have the script start on launch of the Pi.

This is what I have so far

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk
import os
 
camera = PiCamera()
#camera.resolution = (1600,1020)
#camera.preview_fullscreen = False
#camera.preview_window = (115,-100,1600,1500)
camera.rotation = 180
camera.zoom = (0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5)
 
camera.start_preview()
 
# Load the arbitrarily sized image
img = Image.open('crosshair.png')
# Create an image padded to the required size with
# mode 'RGB'
pad = Image.new('RGBA', (
    ((img.size[0] + 31) // 32) * 32,
    ((img.size[1] + 15) // 16) * 16,
    ))
# Paste the original image into the padded one
pad.paste(img, (0, 0))
 
# Add the picture overlay with the padded image as the source,
# but the original image's dimensions
o = camera.add_overlay(pad.tobytes(), size=img.size, layer=3)
# By default, the overlay is in layer 0, beneath the
# preview (which defaults to layer 2). Here we make
# the new overlay semi-transparent, then move it above
# the preview
o.fullscreen = False
o.window = (750, 350, 400, 400)
o.alpha = 255
o.layer = 3
 
# Create a function to close the overlays and stop the camera preview
def dome_shutdown(event=None):
    camera.remove_overlay(o)
    camera.stop_preview()
    root.destroy()
    # Shutdown the Raspberry Pi
    os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
 
# Create a function to close the overlays and stop the camera preview
def close_overlays(event=None):
    camera.remove_overlay(o)
    camera.stop_preview()
    root.destroy()
 
# Create a tkinter window and add a button to close the overlays
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Camera Preview")
shutdown_button = tk.Button(root, text="Shut\nDown", font=("Helvetica", 24), command=dome_shutdown)
shutdown_button.pack(side="top")
#close_button = tk.Button(root, text="Close", font=("Helvetica", 24), command=dome_shutdown)
#close_button.pack(side="bottom")
 
# Bind the escape key to the close_overlays function
root.bind("<Escape>", dome_shutdown)
root.bind("<grave>", close_overlays)
 
#
```